# Video parallax effect

Tags: css3, html5

Хочу сделать видое с эффектом parallax. Для этого создаю блок и в него помещаю видео. Даю `z-index: -1;`, чтобы оно ушло на задний план. Но его все равно видно в тех местах где нет фона. Можно ли как-то спрятать ту часть видео, что выходит за блок, но сохранить при этом эффект parallax. Или же подскажите другой метод получить желаемое. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
CSS

```
#box{
    height:300px;
    left:0;
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
}

#video{
    bottom:0;
    height:auto;
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    right:0;
    width:auto;
    z-index:-1;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div id="box">
    <video class="visible-desktop" id="video" autoplay loop muted>
        <source type="video/mp4" src="video\source1.mp4"></source>
        <source type="video/webm" src="video\source2.webm"></source>
    </video>
</div>
```